# Finding specific instance in a list when the list starts with a comma

Tags: loops, coldfusion, lucee

I'm uploading a spreadsheet and mapping the spreadsheet column headings to those in my database. The email column is the only one that is required. In StringB below, the `,,,` simply indicates that a column was skipped/ignored.

The meat of my question is this:

I have a string of text (StringA) comes from a spreadsheet that I need to find in another string of text (StringB) which matches my database (this is not the real values, just made it simple to illustrate my problem so hopefully this is clear).

StringA:  `YR,MNTH,ANNIVERSARIES,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,EMAIL,NOTES`
StringB:  `,YEAR,,MONTH,LastName,Email,Comments`  <-- this list is dynamic

*MNTH* and *MONTH* are intentionally different;

```
excelColumnList = 'YR,MNTH,ANNIV,FIRST NAME,LAST NAME,EMAIL,NOTES';  
mappedColumnList=  ',YEAR,,MONTH,,First Name,Last Name,Email,COMMENTS';  
mappedColumn= 'Last Name';    

local.index = ListFindNoCase(mappedColumnList, mappedColumn,',', true);

local.returnValue = "";

if ( local.index > 0 )

    local.returnValue = ListGetAt(excelColumnList, local.index);

writedump(local.returnValue);   // dumps "EMAIL" which is wrong
```

The problem I'm having is the index returned when StringB starts with a `,` returns the wrong index value which affects the mapping later. If StringB starts with a word, the process works perfectly. Is there a better way to to get the index when StringB starts with a `,`?

I also tried using `listtoarray` and then `arraytolist` to clean it up but the index is still off and I cannot reliably just add +1 to the index to identify the correct item in the list.

On the other hand, I was considering this `mappedColumnList = right(mappedColumnList,len(mappedColumnList)-1)` to remove the leading `,` which still throws my index values off BUT I could account for that by adding 1 to the index and this appears to be reliably at first glance. Just concerned this is a sort of hack.

Any advice?

https://cfdocs.org/listfindnocase

Here is a cfgist: https://trycf.com/gist/4b087b40ae4cb4499c2b0ddf0727541b/lucee5?theme=monokai

UPDATED
I accepted the answer using EDIT #1. I also added a comment here: [Finding specific instance in a list when the list starts with a comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51434906/finding-specific-instance-in-a-list-when-the-list-starts-with-a-comma?noredirect=1#comment89873471_51443755)

Comment: Just realized, my answer assumes that you want to strip _ALL_ leading commas instead of just the first comma. Is this the intent? If not, my code can be modified to only strip the first comma.

Comment: Also just realized that this code can be very fragile if your Excel or database column names change. You'll want to make sure that you can't exceed the bounds of the `excelColumnList` in your `ListGetAt()` function. Lists in CF start with an index of 1 and `ListGetAt()` will count empty elements, so `Last Name` is the 5th element in `mappedColumnList` after leading commas are stripped. Check the extra column in your example. `StringB` and `mappedColumnList` are different. Was that supposed to be like that?

Comment: If you fix that extra comma in `mappedColumnList`, then your code returns what you're expecting. Without seeing how those variables are made, I'm not sure which one is correct.

Comment: I’ll be in the office in about 40 minutes and can better reply then. So sorry for the delay.

Comment: I added one more correction/comment to my answer. I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, but you may be better off handling the string index syncing further upstream. Also, I think there may be a typo in your `mappedColumnList` variable at `YEAR,,MONTH,,First Name`, I assumed that only one of those double-commas should be there >>> that should be 4 columns instead of 5.

Comment: There is mapping loop to identify the order of the columns in the spreadsheet and the database. When the user uploads their spreadsheet, they may only want to import first name, last name, and email. They have the option to ignore other columns (age, address, sex, etc.) which is why you are seeing `,,` in the above example. They simply preserve the index.

Comment: Your comment of `ListGetAt()` being out of bounds would normally be a concern but the GUI provides a way for the user to map their columns to those of the database so that _shouldn't_ be a problem. However, the user could select two columns to represent the `first name` for example so I need to figure out how to restrict that from happening.

Comment: Right, but is that extra `,,` supposed to be there. It will throw off your indexing.

Comment: If `StringA` comes from the user's Excel sheet, and _they_ specify how those fields map to the database fields, then there should be an easier way to pass those mappings back, like a struct or something. If nothing else, then their string should be modified to fit your database structure. The index is getting off because extra "columns" are being added to the string.

Comment: Is the Excel to DB mapping being done in ColdFusion or in another language?

Comment: You are correct in that it _would_ throw off the index but on the GUI, there is some JavaScript in place to prevent that. The Excel to DB is being done in ColdFusion (Luee 5.x).

Comment: I would look at that Javascript then. You have 7 columns in `excelColumnList` but 8 columns in `mappedColumnList` if you remove the leading comma and count the internal empty elements. That's how the code is trying to access `listGetAt(excelColumnList,8)`.

Comment: Okay, it clicked now - I understand what you are stating. I was tunnel-visioned thinking my faux data above was just flawed but you are correct. Taking another look.

Comment: If `mappedColumnList` is being generated by the JS, can you edit to not include that leading comma? I'm guessing it generates a list like `,element1` and then just appends `,element2` to it, so that it doesn't have a trailing comma ( which would be easier to get rid of, btw :-) ).

Comment: JS is only controlling the UI/UX, not generating the looping. I understand the gap and I'm composing a better description.

Comment: Please allow me to wipe the egg off of my face. Turns out this MIGHT be a JavaScript issue and not a CF Issue. There is an onClick event tied to the submit button. It grabs the selects values from all the selects, pushes them into an array and appends it to a hidden from field which is included on form submit. I may just need to modify that to ignore selects that do not have a value selected.

Comment: If you can, I'd pass it through in some way that you can keep the fields related to each other. That way you don't have to try to re-associate them correctly on the other end. And watch out for injection opportunities. ie if you know what your out results for your table columns will be, whitelist those before it goes to SQL.

Comment: Injection attempts are being handled but it's always a good reminder. :D

Comment: I get nervous when I hear "Javascript" and "database" in the same conversation. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify and strip the "," off the list if it is the first character.

**EDIT: Changed to a `while` loop to identify multiple leading ","s.**

Try:

```
while(left(mappedColumnList,1) == ",") {
    mappedColumnList = right( mappedColumnList,(len(mappedColumnList)-1) ) ;
}
```

https://trycf.com/gist/64287c72d5f54e1da294cc2c10b5ad86/acf2016?theme=monokai

**EDIT 2:** Or even better, if you don't mind dropping back into Java (and a little Regex), you can skip the loop completely. Super efficient.

```
mappedColumnList =  mappedColumnList.replaceall("^(,*)","") ;
```

And then drop the `while` loop completely.

https://trycf.com/gist/346a005cdb72b844a83ca21eacb85035/acf2016?theme=monokai

```
<cfscript>
excelColumnList = 'YR,MNTH,ANNIV,FIRST NAME,LAST NAME,EMAIL,NOTES';
mappedColumnList=  ',,,YEAR,MONTH,,First Name,Last Name,Email,COMMENTS';  
mappedColumn= 'Last Name';    

mappedColumnList =  mappedColumnList.replaceall("^(,*)","") ;

local.index = ListFindNoCase(mappedColumnList, mappedColumn,',', true);

local.returnValue = ListGetAt(excelColumnList,local.index,",",true) ;

writeDump(local.returnValue);
</cfscript>
```

Explanation of the Regex `^(,*)`:

- `^` = Start at the beginning of the string.
- `()` = Capture this group of characters
- `,*` = A literal comma and all consecutive repeats.

So `^(,*)` says, start at the beginning of the string and capture all consecutive commas until reaching the next non-matched character. Then the `replaceall()` just replaces that set of matched characters with an empty string.

**EDIT 3:** I fixed a typo in my original answer. I was only using one list.

`writeOutput(arraytoList(listtoArray(mappedColumnList)))` will get rid of your leading commas, but this is because it will drop empty elements before it becomes an array. This throws your indexing off because you have one empty element in your original `mappedColumnList` string. The later string functions will both read and index that empty element. So, to keep your indexes working like you see to, you'll either need to make sure that your Excel and db columns are always in the same order or you'll have to create some sort of mapping for each of the column names and then perform the `ListGetAt()` on the string you need to use.

Comment: HIi Shawn. Here’s the cfgist with your proposal assuming I placed it where you intended. It does  not produce the correct output. https://trycf.com/gist/f26af1a38994d87bb773347fb77446b6/lucee5?theme=monokai

Comment: I added a cfgist to my question to play with as well.

Comment: Check the Gist I added to my answer.

Comment: I changed my answer to handle multiple leading ","s.

Comment: Initial review looks great. I’ll run it through its paces once I get to work (on phone ATM). Smart usage of the loop.

Comment: @HPWD Check my second suggestion with the Java `replaceall()` method. Much more efficient than the loop.

Comment: And just adding my opinion, being able to fall back into Java when needed is one of the best things about ColdFusion. (Especially when dealing with Strings.)

Comment: This is a new process so unsure of the potential just yet regarding multiple leading commas. The single leading was discovered almost immediately in the error logs. I now know how it gets there and can reproduce it. I’ve not attempted to create a scenario in which there the could be multiple leading commas yet. That’s on todays agenda. :)

Comment: I do wish CF/Lucee was not regarded as the red-headed step-child of web development.

Comment: Edit #1 appears to work well; will need to run it through the code and not rely on just the cfgist for confirmation of course.

Edit #2 fails when mapped column is looking for `COMMENTS`. The inner command (,) are important and should not be removed. In the listFindNoCase, there is an optional value includeEmptyValues which defaults to false whereas due to there importance for this usage, was changed to TRUE (I only recently learned about this optional argument).

Comment: Edit #3 Just for grins, I did try the listtoarray and then arraytolist and it did exactly what I suspect when I stepped away and came back with fresh eyes. You are correct, it definitely throws off the indexing.

Comment: MARKING THIS AS CORRECT, SPECIFICALLY #1 (USING THE WHILE LOOP). I also changed some logic in the code prior to hitting this loop which simplified this process greatly. Instead of passing "NULL" values from the select, I simply added "ignore" to the value. Now there are no more "blank" spaces to contend with. We have a framework actions in place to check for injections. I mention this only for other readers who may find this to be aware.

Answer (score 0):

By default many CF list functions ignore empty elements. A flag was added to these function so that you could disable this behavior. If you have string `,,1,2,3` by default listToArray would consider that 3 elements but `listToArray(listVar, ",", true)` will return 5 with first two as empty strings. ListGetAt has the same "includeEmptyValues" flag so your code should work consistently when that is set to true.